# Failed to validate the specific section of the XML in JAXB if namespace exists

Tags: validation, namespaces, jaxb, stax

I'm using XSD to validate the specific section of the XML in JAXB, but it is failed due to XML namespace, can you advice? Thanks in advance.

Error is "cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'c:MessageDtl'"

**XSD**

***parent.xsd***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema
   targetNamespace="ns.parent"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:c="ns.child"
    xmlns="ns.parent">
    <xs:import schemaLocation="child.xsd" namespace="ns.child"></xs:import>
    <xs:complexType name="MessageType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Message" type="c:Document"></xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="Message" type="MessageType"></xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

***child.xsd***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema
    xmlns="ns.child"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="ns.child"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="Document" type="Document"/>
    <xs:complexType name="Document">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="MessageDtl" type="MessageDtl"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="MessageDtl">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="field1" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="field2" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Message xmlns="ns.parent"
    xmlns:c="ns.child"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xs:schemaLocation="ns.parent parent.xsd ns.child child.xsd">
    <Message>
        <c:MessageDtl>
            <c:field1>field 1</c:field1>
            <c:field2>field 2</c:field2>
        </c:MessageDtl>
    </Message>
</Message>
```

**Sample Code**

```
public class TestXmlValidator {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SchemaFactory SCHEMA_FACTORY = SchemaFactory.newInstance("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
        Schema schema = SCHEMA_FACTORY.newSchema(new File("D:/researches/xmlvalidation/xsd/parent.xsd"));

        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.test");
        SAXSource saxSource = new SAXSource(new InputSource(new FileInputStream("d:/researches/xmlvalidation/sample.xml")));

        InputFactoryImpl XML_INPUT_FACTORY; //fastxml
        XML_INPUT_FACTORY = new com.fasterxml.aalto.stax.InputFactoryImpl();
        XML_INPUT_FACTORY.setProperty(XML_INPUT_FACTORY.IS_NAMESPACE_AWARE, Boolean.TRUE);
        XML_INPUT_FACTORY.setProperty(XML_INPUT_FACTORY.IS_VALIDATING, Boolean.TRUE);
        XML_INPUT_FACTORY.configureForSpeed();

        XMLEventReader2 xmlEventReader = (XMLEventReader2) XML_INPUT_FACTORY.createXMLEventReader(saxSource);

        XMLEvent event;
        while ((event = xmlEventReader.peek()) != null) {
            if(event.isStartElement()){
                System.out.println("=====> " + event.asStartElement().getName().getLocalPart());
                if("MessageDtl".equals(event.asStartElement().getName().getLocalPart())){
                    break;
                }
            }
            xmlEventReader.nextEvent();
        }

        ParseValidationExceptionHandler validationHandler = new ParseValidationExceptionHandler();
        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        jaxbUnmarshaller.setEventHandler(validationHandler);
        jaxbUnmarshaller.setSchema(schema);
        JAXBElement<MessageDtl> result = jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlEventReader, MessageDtl.class);

        if(validationHandler.getEvents() != null && validationHandler.getEvents().length>0){
            for(ValidationEvent e : validationHandler.getEvents()){
                System.out.println("=====> " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        xmlEventReader.close();
        System.out.println("Completed.");
    }
}

class ParseValidationExceptionHandler implements ValidationEventHandler {
    private final List<ValidationEvent> events = new ArrayList<ValidationEvent>();

    public ValidationEvent[] getEvents() {
        return events.toArray(new ValidationEvent[events.size()]);
    }

    public boolean handleEvent( ValidationEvent event ) {
        events.add(event);
        return true;
    }
}
```

But, if we are trying to validate the whole XML, it is success. Below is the sample code.

```
public class TestXmlValidator {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SchemaFactory SCHEMA_FACTORY = SchemaFactory.newInstance("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
        Schema schema = SCHEMA_FACTORY.newSchema(new File("D:/researches/xmlvalidation/xsd/parent.xsd"));
        Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
        SAXSource saxSource = new SAXSource(new InputSource(new FileInputStream("d:/researches/xmlvalidation/sample.xml")));
        validator.validate(saxSource);
        System.out.println("Completed.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have specified an instance of `Schema` on the `Unmarshaller`, the unmarshal operation will be done with schema validation enabled (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/jaxb-and-marshalunmarshal-schema.html).

```java
    jaxbUnmarshaller.setSchema(schema);
    JAXBElement<MessageDtl> result = jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlEventReader, MessageDtl.class);
```

Even though you have advanced the `XMLEventReader` to the `c:MessageDetail` which is a nested element, JAXB is going to treat it like a root element when it starts unmarshalling.  The validation is happening in the unmarshal so the first thing that will happen is a root element called `MessageDetail` will be looked for in the XML schema, since this isn't present the validation will fail.

**Solutions**

1. Change the XML schema so `MessageDetail` is a global element.
2. Find and use a validating `XMLEventReader`

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply. My xml is a **big** xml, there are **thousants of MessageDetail** in my xml, and I have a requirement that **ignore the specific MessageDetail** and continue to process the next **MessageDetail** if the specific **MessageDetail** is validating failed.    
I can understand your reply, but can't understand your solutions, could you share more details? Or can you share some key words so that I can google it. Thanks again. @Blaise Doughan